# How to use scrollintoview inside useeffect ( Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView') )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to set my webPage from beginning to start. So I write code like this.

```
function BasicDetails() {

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        scrollView();
    }, []);

    function scrollView() {
        document.getElementById('main-root').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
    return (
        <Nav>
            <div id="main-root" style={{scrollBehavior: 'smooth'}}>
                <div>
                    <Header pageTitle={'Shop Settings'}/>
                    <Button
                        onClick={saveBasicDetails}
                        variant="contained"
                        id='save'
                        className={classes.saveButton}>
                        SAVE
                    </Button>
                </div>

                <BasicDetailsData style={{scrollBehavior: 'smooth'}} ref={childRef}/>
            </div>
        </Nav>
    );
}
```

But When I Tried to run my code, I have an **error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')**
So I tried many times but can't find the error.
I am a new student for react, so. I don't know much about it.
Anyone can help me with this...I really need your help..thank you.

Comment: You have to use `refs` in React to be able to retrieve a reference to a DOM element, not directly try to call element which is not even rendered - document.getElementById('main-root') - it's not existing in the DOM element as you're making it first in Virtual DOM.  https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Other than you should use a Rect ref instead of querying the DOM for the element, I can't reproduce the issue in a pared down codesandbox using `document.getElementById('main-root')`, it doesn't throw an error. Can you try to create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we can inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this out and this is how I got it to work:

```js
function scrollView() {
    const mainRoot = document.getElementById("main-root");
    mainRoot.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much..✌️❤️